# Mybatis" Need to manage connections/datasources independently

Tags: jdbc, datasource, ibatis, mybatis

Because of our architecture, we need to manage datasources independently of the Ibatis mappers.

I am having trouble finding out how to set the connection and/or datasource for the Ibatis sessions rather than letting it do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to manage 2 instances of SqlSessionFactory.  That's not ideal, but if you have to.

Also,  I'd check out the [Mybatis Guice](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Guice) or Spring integration.  Perhaps using Dependency Injection, with your own Data Source Provider, you could achieve your desired behavior.